# Powershell update users from one custom permission level to Full Control

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-permissions

Looking for PowerShell opportunity to find all users in our site collection that are tagged as a custom permission level "Administrator" and change them to "Full Control".  If they are added as a user, then update them...i.e. if they are "Administrator" on a list, then update them to Full Control.  If there is a SharePoint group, we also want to update that group to Full Control.

Comment: Would it make sense to just grant your "Administrator" group "Full Control"?

Comment: Hi Mike...yes, they are almost identical and the 'Admin' group was created back in the SP 2007 days.  If we can get rid of this 'Administrator' group, our reports with ShareGate will be better and provide more flexibility/filtering.  Point being is we'd like to get rid of this 'Administrator' permission level altogether.